# Pass data between view controllers on start up

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

I have a side menu app.

I have 2 `ViewController`'s `RearViewController` and `FrontViewController`.

In `RearViewController` I have a `tableView` and I want as soon as the app start `FrontViewController` to load the first element from this table.

I have tried adding

```
frontViewController.category = [rearViewController.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0]];
```

in `AppDelegate`, but all it get is a nil object.
Thank you.

Comment: It is coming nil in appDelegate as it had no value in AppDelegate...your objects will have no value till the time the method containing them is called!!

Comment: What do you want..... ??? you want to get variable backward ????
How is it possible ?

Answer (score 0):

The data wont be sent from one view controller to another like this .... You have to push it ... Use pushViewController
In the `RearViewController` write...

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:FirstViewController animated:YES];
```

Comment: I don't get it. My root controller is FrontViewController, and I couldn't understand what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

I use protocol in this case.

```
@protocol CommonDataSource
- (TheType *)dataSource;
@end


@interface AppDelegate : NSObject <UIAppDelegate, CommonDataSource>
@end

@implementation AppDelegate
- (TheType *)dataSource
{
   ...
}
@end


@interface TheAViewController : UIViewController
@property (...) id<CommonDataSource> commonDataSource;
@end

@interface TheBViewController : UIViewController
@property (...) id<CommonDataSource> commonDataSource;
@end


- (IBAction)theActionA:(id)sender
{
   TheAViewController *aaa = ...;
   a.commonDataSource = (AppDelegate*)...;
}


- (IBAction)theActionB:(id)sender
{
   TheAViewController *aaa = ...;
   a.commonDataSource = (AppDelegate*)...;
}
```

Good luck!